# Python Pandas selecting the location with the most coordinates

Tags: python, pandas

I am having issues selecting the location with the most coordinates. I currently have the following csv file with a table organized in two columns as presented:
(The coordinates column is a concat of latitude and longitude)

```
----------
Location | Coordinates

A   |        "-13.45", "16.59", "12.28" 

B   |        "-13.45", "18.-20", "19.30", "-19.-31" , "-19.313", "-1193.313", "-293.31", "273.31", "232.31", "253.321"

C   |        "-13.45", "18.-20", "19.30", "-19.-31" , "-19.313", "-1193.313", "-293.31", "273.31", "232.31", "292.53", "-52.18"
```

My goal is to capture for each location the next location with the most coordinates (of all locations in the csv file including the original one) and where the number of coordinates is at least 90% similar to the original location

```
A   |        A   |    1 

B   |        C   |  0.9

C   |        C | 1
```

So in sum it should print the location with the largest number of coordinates and similarity in terms of coordinates of at least or more than 90% to the original location.

Is such a thing feasible in Pandas?

Thank you.

Comment: Does `"-19.-31"` mean `(-19, -31)` (lat, long)?

Comment: It is a concat of lat and long I made it smaller to simplify but it should be something like this "-0.22389251.572662"

Comment: How can you tell whether `"-0.22389251.572662"` means `(-0.2238, 9251.572662)` or `(-0.22389, 251.572662)` or `(-0.2238925, 1.572662)`?  The whole question would be more clear if your input data were not confusing.

Comment: Why do you want to slice the concat anyway?